# How to use a static method from another class without ::

Tags: c++, static-methods

I am new to C++ and as a requirement for a program, I must use a pre-written main file. In that file, a method from another class is called as if it were defined in the main file. An example of this code is shown below.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
   cout << factorial(5);
   return 0;
}
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    static int factorial(int);
}
#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include foo.h
int foo::factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

The error that is produced is:

```
'factorial': identifier not found
```

If I were to replace cout << factorial(5) with cout << foo::factorial(5), then the program runs perfectly.

However, the main that was provided calls foo as if it was defined in main.cpp as shown in the first code block.

All the posts I found on similar topics were just "How to call methods of another class" answer: static method. But even with a static method, you must use foo::factorial(int) right? How do I call factorial(int) in main.cpp?

Comment: You need to show the real code you were presented, on whatever silly online quiz site where you found this. This is clearly not real code, but fake code, since what's allegedly in so-called "foo.cpp" does not even match the contents of so-called "foo.h" (and foo.cpp won't even compile, as is, by itself).

Comment: If the only file you're provided is `main.cpp`, why do you think that `factorial()` is a class method rather than just a plain function?   As pointed out in the other comment, your `foo.h` and `foo.cpp` are also not self-consistent.

Comment: I tried to simplify as much as possible to remove uneeded code, but I will upload the full program in about 10 minutes, as I'm walking to a library

Comment: No. Do not "upload the full program". Nobody wants to see a "full program". That would be off-topic for stackoverflow.com. See the instructions for creating a [mcve] in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a separate include file (in this case `"foo.h"`) is not required to map to a class called `Foo`. The included file can just declare the function `factorial` as a free function and define it in `foo.cpp`.

foo.hpp

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int factorial(int);

#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try declaring it as a free function

Answer (score 1):

> How to use a static method from another class without ::

You can't in this case. There are cases where this is possible where *argument dependent lookup* applies. ADL doesn't apply here, since the arguments are literals.

> How do I call factorial(int) in main.cpp?

Using the scope resolution operator `::`.

Your desire of calling without scope resolution, and the desire of using a static member function are in a conflict. You must choose one desire, and give up on it. If modifying `main.cpp` isn't an option, then you have to use a free function that is visible in the global namespace, instead of a member function.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination of the constraints of the scope resolution operator